# Paging, sorting and filtering in a stored procedure (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was looking at different ways of writing a stored procedure to return a "page" of data. This was for use with the ASP `ObjectDataSource`, but it could be considered a more general problem.

The requirement is to return a subset of the data based on the usual paging parameters; `startPageIndex` and `maximumRows`, but also a `sortBy` parameter to allow the data to be sorted. Also there are some parameters passed in to filter the data on various conditions.

One common way to do this seems to be something like this:

[Method 1]

```sql
;WITH stuff AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN @SortBy = 'Name' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
            WHEN @SortBy = 'Name DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name DESC)
            WHEN @SortBy = ... 
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever)
        END AS Row,
        ., 
        ., 
        .,
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ...
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ...
    WHERE ... (lots of things to check)
    ) 
SELECT *
FROM stuff 
WHERE (Row > @startRowIndex)
AND   (Row <= @startRowIndex + @maximumRows OR @maximumRows <= 0)
ORDER BY Row
```

One problem with this is that it doesn't give the total count and generally we need another stored procedure for that. This second stored procedure has to replicate the parameter list and the complex `WHERE` clause. Not nice.

One solution is to append an extra column to the final select list, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stuff) AS `TotalRows`. This gives us the total but repeats it for every row in the result set, which is not ideal.

[Method 2]
An interesting alternative is given here (https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111700/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032206-1.aspx) using dynamic SQL. He reckons that the performance is better because the CASE statement in the first solution drags things down. Fair enough, and this solution makes it easy to get the totalRows and slap it into an output parameter. But I hate coding dynamic SQL. All that 'bit of SQL ' + STR(@parm1) +' bit more SQL' gubbins.

[Method 3]
The only way I can find to get what I want, without repeating code which would have to be synchronized, and keeping things reasonably readable is to go back to the "old way" of using a table variable:

```sql
DECLARE @stuff TABLE (Row INT, ...)

INSERT INTO @stuff
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortBy = 'Name' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
        WHEN @SortBy = 'Name DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name DESC)
        WHEN @SortBy = ... 
        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever)
    END AS Row,
    ., 
    ., 
    .,
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ...
LEFT JOIN Table3 ...
WHERE ... (lots of things to check)

SELECT *
FROM stuff 
WHERE (Row > @startRowIndex)
AND   (Row <= @startRowIndex + @maximumRows OR @maximumRows <= 0)
ORDER BY Row
```

(Or a similar method using an IDENTITY column on the table variable).
Here I can just add a SELECT COUNT on the table variable to get the totalRows and put it into an output parameter.

I did some tests and with a fairly simple version of the query (no sortBy and no filter), method 1 seems to come up on top (almost twice as quick as the other 2). Then I decided to test probably I needed the complexity and I needed the SQL to be in stored procedures. With this I get method 1 taking nearly twice as long as the other 2 methods. Which seems strange.

Is there any good reason why I shouldn't spurn CTEs and stick with method 3?

---

### UPDATE - 15 March 2012

I tried adapting Method 1 to dump the page from the CTE into a temporary table so that I could extract the TotalRows and then select just the relevant columns for the resultset. This seemed to add significantly to the time (more than I expected). I should add that I'm running this on a laptop with SQL Server Express 2008 (all that I have available) but still the comparison should be valid.

I looked again at the dynamic SQL method. It turns out I wasn't really doing it properly (just concatenating strings together). I set it up as in the documentation for `sp_executesql` (with a parameter description string and parameter list) and it's much more readable. Also this method runs fastest in my environment. Why that should be still baffles me, but I guess the answer is hinted at in Hogan's comment.

Comment: This is all about your server and expected use.  CTE's use more memory... if ya got a lot of memory you are probably good.  Method 3 uses a lot of disk space.  If you have multiple cores and a physical  file for each core in temp this will probably work best (why I expect yours worked so well.)

Comment: I did not look at 2 but unless your data is static 1 and 3 are flawed.  Get records 1-50 and then get records 51-100.  Them someone changes a sort value and record 49 is now record 999.  Then you get records that by count are 101-150 but you actually missed record 101.  You can chain commands.  select count(*) where ...; select top 40 from ... where ... and Sort > lastSortMax order by Sort1;

Comment: @Blam - I think this may be a matter of opinion. I would want changes to appear. Striving to make paging constant and missing any database changes is flawed (IMO).

Comment: @Fruitbat No your logic is flawed. 9 items a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, and i.  I get the first 3. Then someone changes c to z so I have a, b, d, e, f, g, h, i,  and z.  Then I get the next 3 (with your logic) and I get e, f, and g.  Totally missed D.  Static increments from dynamic data will results in gaps and overlaps.

Comment: @Blam. From my point of view, that is just expected behaviour. I.e. changes can occur so be aware of them. I think I understand your first comment more clearly now (lastSortMax being the bottom of the previous page), but this is not a method of paging that I've seen before. What happens if you have identical sort keys split over 2 pages?

Comment: @Fruitbat Start with the basics. A single sort key.  In this scenario record d had not changed but was skipped.  If a static record can be skipped then I call that flawed logic.  And a bad flaw - it is one thing to present the same record twice - but not present a record is a hard flaw.  As for more complex issues you  have to add the PK to the user sort as a tie breaker.  Your approach of evaluate it all, all over again and take a static slice is not only memory and CPU intensive it is open to gaps and overlaps.  Man up an write a more complex where.

Comment: @Fruitbat And you a think stored procedure executed against static data multiple time will present ties in the same order?

Comment: @Blam - You have a good point and it's starting to make sense to me but I need to spend more time thinking about it. But a couple of points: 1. It's a side issue. The question still remains about the balance between maintainable code and performance. 2. I'm finding your tone slightly aggressive. I think you should be more patient in your explanations and refrain from asking me to "man up". I never suggested that I was averse to writing a complex WHERE, I just don't want to write an identical complex WHERE in more than one place.

Comment: @Fruitbat Below you complained "The complexity of the WHERE clause would have to be replicated."  If you have duplicate code then your program is not structured properly.  You do know you can store text in a string variable?

Answer (score 7):

I would most likely split the `@SortBy` argument into two, `@SortColumn` and `@SortDirection`, and use them like this:

```
…
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  ORDER BY CASE @SortColumn
    WHEN 'Name'      THEN Name
    WHEN 'OtherName' THEN OtherName
    …
  END *
  CASE @SortDirection
    WHEN 'DESC' THEN -1
    ELSE 1
  END
) AS Row
…
```

And this is how the `TotalRows` column could be defined (in the main select):

```
…
COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows
…
```

Comment: Apart from splitting the SortBy, isn't this just my Method 1?

Comment: @Fruitbat: I also use a single `ROW_NUMBER()` and the CASE expression is moved to the `ROW_NUMBER()`'s ORDER BY clause. You may still consider this your Method 1 modified, it's fine by me. :) I was merely suggesting what I would do, and I considered the changes worth posting as an answer.

Comment: Love the `-1` and `1`, too bad something like this can't be used with non-numerics

Comment: Would adding `COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows` to the main selection not add more data to bandwidth than really needed? I was thinking of sending it back as an `OUTPUT`, but then I'd have to write the query twice, right? any implications on that?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs: My suggestions are meant to be used with the OP's Method 1, which is just one SELECT statement providing all the data (in this case, including "metadata" like the row count). A SELECT statement doesn't have (or need) an OUTPUT clause, hence the suggestion to return the count as another column of the output. Yes, the same count will be repeated in all rows, but with Method 1 there's no other way to obtain this piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely want to do a combination of a temp table and `NTILE` for this sort of approach.

The temp table will allow you to do your complicated series of conditions just once. Because you're only storing the pieces you care about, it also means that when you start doing selects against it further in the procedure, it should have a smaller overall memory usage than if you ran the condition multiple times.

I like `NTILE()` for this better than `ROW_NUMBER()` because it's doing the work  you're trying to accomplish for you, rather than having additional `where` conditions to worry about.

The example below is one based off a similar query I'm using as part of a research query; I have an ID I can use that I know will be unique in the results. Using an ID that was an identity column would also be appropriate here, though.

```
--DECLARES here would be stored procedure parameters
declare @pagesize int, @sortby varchar(25), @page int = 1;

--Create temp with all relevant columns; ID here could be an identity PK to help with paging query below
create table #temp (id int not null primary key clustered, status varchar(50), lastname varchar(100), startdate datetime);

--Insert into #temp based off of your complex conditions, but with no attempt at paging
insert into #temp
(id, status, lastname, startdate)
select id, status, lastname, startdate
from Table1 ...etc.
where ...complicated conditions


SET @pagesize = 50;
SET @page = 5;--OR CAST(@startRowIndex/@pagesize as int)+1
SET @sortby = 'name';

--Only use the id and count to use NTILE
;with paging(id, pagenum, totalrows) as 
(
    select id,
    NTILE((SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM #temp)/@pagesize) OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sortby = 'NAME' THEN lastname ELSE convert(varchar(10), startdate, 112) END),
    cnt
    FROM #temp
    cross apply (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM #temp) total
)
--Use the id to join back to main select
SELECT *
FROM paging
JOIN #temp ON paging.id = #temp.id
WHERE paging.pagenum = @page

--Don't need the drop in the procedure, included here for rerunnability
drop table #temp;
```

I generally prefer temp tables over table variables in this scenario, largely so that there are definite statistics on the result set you have. (Search for temp table vs table variable and you'll find plenty of examples as to why)

Dynamic SQL would be most useful for handling the sorting method. Using my example, you could do the main query in dynamic SQL and only pull the sort method you want to pull into the `OVER()`.

The example above also does the total in each row of the return set, which as you mentioned was not ideal. You could, instead, have a `@totalrows` output variable in your procedure and pull it as well as the result set. That would save you the `CROSS APPLY` that I'm doing above in the paging CTE.

Answer (score 0):

I would create one procedure to stage, sort, and paginate (using `NTILE()`) a staging table; and a second procedure to retrieve by page. This way you don't have to run the entire main query for each page.

This example queries AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
create procedure dbo.EmployeesByMartialStatus
@MaritalStatus nchar(1)
, @sort varchar(20)
as

-- Init staging table
if exists(
    select 1 from sys.objects o
    inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id=o.schema_id
    and s.name='Staging'
    and o.name='EmployeesByMartialStatus'
    where type='U'
)
drop table Staging.EmployeesByMartialStatus;

-- Populate staging table with sort value
with s as (
    select *
    , sr=ROW_NUMBER()over(order by case @sort
        when 'NationalIDNumber' then NationalIDNumber
        when 'ManagerID' then ManagerID
        -- plus any other sort conditions
        else EmployeeID end)
    from AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee
    where MaritalStatus=@MaritalStatus
)
select *
into #temp
from s;

-- And now pages
declare @RowCount int; select @rowCount=COUNT(*) from #temp;
declare @PageCount int=ceiling(@rowCount/20); --assuming 20 lines/page
select *
, Page=NTILE(@PageCount)over(order by sr)
into Staging.EmployeesByMartialStatus
from #temp;
go

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- procedure to retrieve selected pages
create procedure EmployeesByMartialStatus_GetPage
@page int
as
declare @MaxPage int;
select @MaxPage=MAX(Page) from Staging.EmployeesByMartialStatus;
set @page=case when @page not between 1 and @MaxPage then 1 else @page end;

select EmployeeID,NationalIDNumber,ContactID,LoginID,ManagerID
, Title,BirthDate,MaritalStatus,Gender,HireDate,SalariedFlag,VacationHours,SickLeaveHours
, CurrentFlag,rowguid,ModifiedDate
from Staging.EmployeesByMartialStatus
where Page=@page
GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Usage

-- Load staging
exec dbo.EmployeesByMartialStatus 'M','NationalIDNumber';

-- Get pages 1 through n    
exec dbo.EmployeesByMartialStatus_GetPage 1;
exec dbo.EmployeesByMartialStatus_GetPage 2;
-- ...etc (this would actually be a foreach loop, but that detail is omitted for brevity)

GO
```

Comment: *marital*, *martial*... à la mariage comme à la guerre :)

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, this seems to miss the point by some distance. The complexity of the WHERE clause would have to be replicated. There would have to be a staging table for each possible sort and filter. Unless you create the staging table each time, you won't show the latest changes to the database.

Comment: @Fruitbat - The staging table is created once for each report run, where it is sorted and paginated. A separate sproc is then run to deliver a page at a time. Separating the operations prevents the complex WHERE clause from being repeated for each page, which is what would happen if all steps were combined into one sproc. Only one sort is selected at a time, and because the two procedures would be run back-to-back for each report, the latest updates to the DB would always be included.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. E.g. I search for names containing 'abc', sorted by name. As I page through the results, a new record is added to the database which matches my criteria. How can I pick this up without running sproc1 again? I'm not clear what you mean by "report run" in this context.

Comment: The idea here is to execute dbo.EmployeesByMartialStatus once for the report run, and then EmployeesByMartialStatus_GetPage n times for each of n number of pages. EmployeesByMartialStatus_GetPage only reads the staging table.

Comment: Usage example updated to show the first sproc being called once, and the second sproc being called multiple times.

Comment: This does not solve the problem.  An expected use case is two users requesting paging at the same time with different sort orders (and possibly different filters) -- having to build and rebuild the table(s) on each query would be way to slow and impossible to manage unless there were multiple results stored in the result table -- if you have that much space there are better ways to solve this problem with savvy index creation.

Comment: @Fruitbat So you get that adding a record that matches the criteria will change the results from the SP but you don't get that it also changes that 51-100 may not follow the the prior 1-50.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method of using `EXEC()`:

```
-- SP parameters:
-- @query: Your query as an input parameter
-- @maximumRows: As number of rows per page
-- @startPageIndex: As number of page to filter
-- @sortBy: As a field name or field names with supporting DESC keyword
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM sys.Objects', 
        @maximumRows int = 8,
        @startPageIndex int = 3,
        @sortBy as nvarchar(100) = 'name Desc'

SET @query = ';WITH CTE AS (' + @query + ')' +
            'SELECT *, (dt.pagingRowNo - 1) / ' + CAST(@maximumRows as nvarchar(10)) + ' + 1 As pagingPageNo' +
                ', pagingCountRow / ' + CAST(@maximumRows as nvarchar(10)) + ' As pagingCountPage ' +
                ', (dt.pagingRowNo - 1) % ' + CAST(@maximumRows as nvarchar(10)) + ' + 1 As pagingRowInPage ' +
            'FROM (  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sortBy + ') As pagingRowNo, COUNT(*) OVER () AS pagingCountRow ' +
                    'FROM CTE) dt ' +
            'WHERE (dt.pagingRowNo - 1) / ' + CAST(@maximumRows as nvarchar(10)) + ' + 1 = ' + CAST(@startPageIndex as nvarchar(10))

EXEC(@query)
```

At result-set after query result columns:

> **Note:**
>     I add some extra columns that you can remove them:
>
> ```
>     pagingRowNo : The row number
>  pagingCountRow : The total number of rows
>    pagingPageNo : The current page number 
> pagingCountPage : The total number of pages
> pagingRowInPage : The row number that started with 1 in this page
> ```