# Reload GridView Data with JS to save time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, webmethod

atm I try to reduce my load times in my webpage, for this I try to extract every long loading method to JS or as a PageMethod / WebMethod to load it after the page is build to give the user a better feeling...

Now I have my GridView with an ODS, which is loaded with around 100-200 entrys atm, will be much more if the user doesn't clean up his Private Message Box.
So I want to display the first (lets say) 20 entrys now, and load the other entrys afterwards, so in 99% of the cases the user only want one of the first entrys.

Here is my code atm:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsIncome" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllPMsAsReciepient"
    TypeName="DAL.PMDAL">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="UserID" DbType="Guid" Name="userID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="gridIn" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsIncome"
    OnRowDataBound="gridItemOverview_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" EmptyDataText="Keine Nachrichten vorhanden"
    PageSize="50" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="gridIn_RowCommand" OnPreRender="gridIn_PreRender">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#bfcfde" BorderColor="Gray" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#ccdded" BorderColor="Gray" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#ccdded" BorderColor="Gray" CssClass="emptyDataRow" Height="30px" HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Betreff" HeaderStyle-Width="550px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
            <%--small 675--%>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/unread.png" ID="imgUnread" runat="server" Width="10px" />
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/return3.png" ID="imgAnswered" runat="server" Width="10px" />
                <asp:HyperLink CssClass="pmLink" ID="linkTitle" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("PMID","~/PM/ShowPM.aspx?type=In&id={0}") %>'
                    runat="server"><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Absender" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
            <%--small 250--%>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink CssClass="pmLink" ID="linkSender" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("SenderID","~/User/ShowProfile.aspx?id={0}") %>'
                    runat="server"><%# Eval("User1.Username") %></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="170px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" DataField="Timestamp"
            HeaderText="Datum" SortExpression="Timestamp">
            <%--small 200--%>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" Width="15px" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" runat="server"
                    CommandName="dele" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PMID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Lets say I make a new Method to only load 20 entrys, I can enter the Method in the SelectMethod-Property of the ODS - but how to reload the GridView / ODS after this with a WebMethod or JS to reload all entrys and overwrite the allready drawn table?

Answer (score 0):

Anything done from a WebMethod would have to be reloaded with JavaScript code.  You cannot do this from the server when using web methods.  I would highly recommend using a ListView control, or even better, look to use a templating framework like one of the several plugins from JQuery or other framework.

However, you can get decent performance if you use a stored procedure with a custom paging approach, such as  this:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml
- [Paging, sorting and filtering in a stored procedure (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692583/paging-sorting-and-filtering-in-a-stored-procedure-sql-server)